# What is Texas code for kitchen electrical outlet near sink and cooktop

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I would like to know the permitted height of an electrical outlet from the kitchen sink countertop or cooktop.

Comment: You need to specify the city or county if not in a city. This could well vary.

Comment: @JimStewart -- while that's true in *general* for the NEC, I haven't heard of anyone amending the *specific* Code passage that covers the question here

Answer (score 2):

### The NEC has you covered

This limit is set at 20" above the countertop by NEC 210.52(C)(5):

> **(5) Receptacle Outlet Location.** Receptacle outlets shall
>   be located on or above, but not more than 500 mm (20 in.)
>   above, the countertop. Receptacle outlet assemblies listed
>   for the application shall be permitted to be installed in
>   countertops. Receptacle outlets rendered not readily accessible by appliances fastened in place, appliance garages,
>   sinks, or rangetops as covered in 210.52(C)(1), Exception,
>   or appliances occupying dedicated space shall not be considered as these required outlets.